# Incrementally computing knapsack

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, knapsack-problem, approximation, subset-sum

Is there a way to compute the knapsack problem incrementally? Any approximation algorithm? I am trying to solve the problem in the following scenario.

Let D be my data set which is not ordered and should not be. D is divided into 3 subsets, namely D1, D2 and D3. D1, D2 and D3 can each be ordered if needed. I want to compute separate knapsack solutions for sets (D1,D2) and (D2,D3), but I don't want to avoid computing D2 two times. So, basically, I want to:

- compute (D2) // do some operation
- save it as an intermediate result
- use it with D1 and get knapsack result for (D1, D2)
- use it with D3 and get knapsack result for (D2,D3)

That way the data traversal over D2 is done only once.  Is there a way to solve the knapsack incrementally like this?

Comment: Supposing you mean the 0/1 knapsack problem, yes.  If the usual DP solution is performed for D2 alone then the memoized partial results are suitable for bootstrapping the DP solution for either (D2, D1) or (D2, D3).  To compute solutions for both, you'll want to make a copy of the partial results from the D2-only computation.  I'm not immediately prepared to answer for other variants of the knapsack problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I mean 0/1 knapsack problem. As far as I know, if the combination of (D2,D1) is not sorted, then combining two solutions of DP is not efficient. In my case D1 and D2 are sorted separately and the set S = (D2 U D1) or S= (D2 U D3) is not necessarily sorted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sorted".  The DP @JohnBollinger refers to doesn't care about the order of the elements, so you don't need to do any sorting of them -- all you need to do is move the elements in D2 to the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia gives this pseudocode for 0/1 Knapsack: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem

```
 // Input:
 // Values (stored in array v)
 // Weights (stored in array w)
 // Number of distinct items (n)
 // Knapsack capacity (W)

 for j from 0 to W do:
     m[0, j] := 0

 for i from 1 to n do:
     for j from 0 to W do:
         if w[i-1] > j then:
             m[i, j] := m[i-1, j]
         else:
             m[i, j] := max(m[i-1, j], m[i-1, j-w[i-1]] + v[i-1])
```

This builds a 2 dimensional array such that `m[n, W]` (the last element in the last row) is the solution -- you run this on D2.

Then you write another algorithm that takes this array as input and

1. Does not do the `for j ...` part to initialize the array
2. Does `for i from D2.count+1 to (D2.count + other.count) do:` to start where the other one left off. (you have to adjust i when looking up in the w and v arrays)